# Why/how does monero generate public ed25519 keys without using the standard public key generation provided by ed25519 libraries?

Tags: cryptography, address, elliptic-curve

Why/how does monero generate public ed25519 keys without using the standard public key derivation provided by ed25519 libraries?

Inspecting the code for mininero (https://github.com/monero-project/mininero/blob/master/mininero.py), it seems that it doesn't call the ed25519 publickey method to generate public keys. Instead, it defines its own public_key method that does this:

```
ed25519.encodepoint(ed25519.scalarmultbase(sk))
```

Mininero's copy of the ed25519 library (from http://ed25519.cr.yp.to/software.html) provides a function called "publickey", which appears to be identical in purpose to the python pynacl and warner/python-ed25519 libraries. All three produce the same resulting public keys. Neither of those other libraries appear to provide an alternative mechanism to derive a public key the way mininero does, nor do they provide any methods to mirror the functionality of mininero's ed25519.encodepoint. This leads me to believe that minero is deriving the public spendkey in an alternative way.

Why doesn't it just use the normal public key methods provided by these libraries? What is the reason for deriving the public key this way?

My hunch is that there is a reason to use a different public key generation system because the intent is to use ed25519 for more than just signing something. For background, I'm writing some monero address generation code as a learning project and I noticed that with the same seed, my public keys are not being generated the same way as valid monero code. My code takes the seed:

```
awning ramped obedient frown vaults voice dash sunken talent myriad soggy pumpkins buffet vigilant yields foggy wayside rabbits unplugs sarcasm behind lopped tycoon uttered frown
```

Which produces a spendkey of

```
77fadbe52830d30438ff68036374c0e3fb755d0d983743bcbfb6a45962f50a09
```

My code uses python libraries to generate an ed25519 public spend key. I wrote the code to use either https://github.com/pyca/pynacl or https://github.com/warner/python-ed25519 , which both produce the same result. For my spendkey above:

```
9235e2ecf938d462e79fe993bfdb1717353c87a0b0ed7cb1d58c9692035336d0
```

This doesn't match what the mininero code and https://xmr.llcoins.net/addresstests.html produce for the same spendkey. They both produce `0f3b913371411b27e646b537e888f685bf929ea7aab93c950ed84433f064480d`

Here is a snippet of code that shows the `9235e2ecf938d462e79fe993bfdb1717353c87a0b0ed7cb1d58c9692035336d0` generated public key (ed25519 from warner/python-ed25519):

```
import ed25519
import binascii
spendkey_hex = b'77fadbe52830d30438ff68036374c0e3fb755d0d983743bcbfb6a45962f50a09'
sk = binascii.unhexlify(spendkey_hex)

def sc_reduce32(n):
    n = int.from_bytes(n, byteorder='little')
    l = (2**252 + 27742317777372353535851937790883648493)
    reduced = n % l
    newbytes = reduced.to_bytes(32, 'little')
    return newbytes


reduced_sk = sc_reduce32(sk)
sec = ed25519.SigningKey(reduced_sk)
pub = sec.get_verifying_key()

print('pub key: ' + str(pub.to_ascii(encoding="hex")))
```

Here is a snipped of code that produces `9235e2ecf938d462e79fe993bfdb1717353c87a0b0ed7cb1d58c9692035336d0` using ed25519 from the mininero copy of ed25519.py

```
import ed25519 as ed25519
import binascii
spendkey_hex = b'77fadbe52830d30438ff68036374c0e3fb755d0d983743bcbfb6a45962f50a09'
mininero_pub_spend = ed25519.publickey(binascii.unhexlify(spendkey_hex))
print('pub key: ' + str(binascii.hexlify(mininero_pub_spend)))
```

Comment: how to generate a public key with a private key in Java

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Monero doesn't use EdDSA, which all of those libraries are specifically set up for. We don't use SHA512 at all, but rather Keccak (~SHA3). We don't use secret keys as seeds like EdDSA does, but rather as scalars. If you look at [ed25519.py](http://ed25519.cr.yp.to/python/ed25519.py) on L63, you can see what I'm talking about.

Change the function to look like this:

```
def publickey(sk):
  a = decodeint(sk)
  A = scalarmult(B,a)
  return encodepoint(A)
```

Now you'll get the correct result: `0f3b913371411b27e646b537e888f685bf929ea7aab93c950ed84433f064480d`. I use `binascii.hexlify` to get the output converted to hex (and also `unhexlify` to use the secret key as input to `publickey(sk)`).

Comment: Thank you. I've added a snippet above. I have written a version to use the same functions that mininero uses, and I do get the same public key in that case. Public key generation is pretty slow using a pure python route, and I had to make changes to allow it to work in python3. That's why I was looking for a library to help. It doesn't look like one exists.

Comment: I see references occasionally to EdDSA over in reference to monero. If monero doesn't use EdDSA, is there a name for what we do use? I'm guessing this is something based on cryptonote research?

Comment: Monero uses the curve Ed25519, which EdDSA (reference) also uses. For signatures, Monero uses [FS](https://eprint.iacr.org/2006/389.pdf) ring signatures currently, but will switch to Shen Noether's MLSAGs (along with some others) with RingCT. Monero also uses standard Schnorr sigs (also with Ed25519) for certain (off-blockchain) signing operations.

Comment: Reading more of those linked libraries, it does seem many have equated Ed25519 and EdDSA. It makes sense to me for Ed25519 to refer to the curve (as that's what it is) and for EdDSA to refer to the reference signature scheme using it. pynacl also has a lot of [Curve25519](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve25519) stuff, so maybe that public key you were getting was on that curve?

Comment: I can get pynacl, warner/python-ed25519, and mininero's ed25519 to all generate `9235e2ecf938d462e79fe993bfdb1717353c87a0b0ed7cb1d58c9692035336d0`

The code snippet didn't format very well in the comment, so I'm adding it to my post above.

Comment: I have found a nice, speedy version of the python reference implementation of ed25519. It seems to be nearly a drop-in replacement for the one in mininero (although I haven't tested everything yet), with the exception that it needs scalarmultbase reimplemented (which is easy, as scalarmult is still there).

https://bitbucket.org/dholth/ed25519ll/raw/37719c56b7b621a98dc694b109ccfca1c946ed65/ed25519ll/djbec.py

Comment: Ah thanks, I get it now. I had accidentally left a line edited while screwing around with it.

Comment: @Ryan - since  you seem to have spent a decent bit of time playing around with this, what did you conclude as your best bet for key derivation in Python 3?

Answer (score 0):

Worth pointing out these command level piped facts with the context up top:

1% echo 77fadbe52830d30438ff68036374c0e3fb755d0d983743bcbfb6a45962f50a09 | ./25519
`9235e2ecf938d462e79fe993bfdb1717353c87a0b0ed7cb1d58c9692035336d0`

2% echo 77fadbe52830d30438ff68036374c0e3fb755d0d983743bcbfb6a45962f50a09 | bx sha512 | cut -c 1-64 | ./clamp | ./sc_reduce32 | ./secret_key_to_public_key
`9235e2ecf938d462e79fe993bfdb1717353c87a0b0ed7cb1d58c9692035336d0`

3% echo 77fadbe52830d30438ff68036374c0e3fb755d0d983743bcbfb6a45962f50a09 | bx sha512 | cut -c 1-64

`b359d96c1864b19ba68bb72f474b459294fa4938c3f03cd5260141ddd7349915`

4% echo 77fadbe52830d30438ff68036374c0e3fb755d0d983743bcbfb6a45962f50a09 | bx sha512 | cut -c 1-64 | ./clamp

`b059d96c1864b19ba68bb72f474b459294fa4938c3f03cd5260141ddd7349955`

**Is how Monero converts a private key to a public key:**

5% echo b059d96c1864b19ba68bb72f474b459294fa4938c3f03cd5260141ddd7349955 | ./sc_reduce32 | ./secret_key_to_public_key

`9235e2ecf938d462e79fe993bfdb1717353c87a0b0ed7cb1d58c9692035336d0`

6% echo 77fadbe52830d30438ff68036374c0e3fb755d0d983743bcbfb6a45962f50a09 | ./sc_reduce32 | ./secret_key_to_public_key

`0f3b913371411b27e646b537e888f685bf929ea7aab93c950ed84433f064480d`

**Additional Points:**

1. ./25519 utilizes libsodium's **crypto_sign_ed25519_sk_to_seed()** and **crypto_sign_seed_keypair()** functions.
2. ./sc_reduce32 utilizes libsodium's **crypto_core_ed25519_scalar_reduce()** function.
3. ./secret_key_to_public_key utilizes libsodium's **crypto_scalarmult_ed25519_base_noclamp()** function.
4. ./clamp performs this:

```
  // Big Endian Clamping
  // https://quirks.ed25519.info/basics/
  // % echo 7ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff8 | ./endian32
  //        f8ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff7f  
  // https://moderncrypto.org/mail-archive/curves/2017/000861.html; 64 = 0x40

  output[0]  &= (unsigned char)0xf8;
  output[31] &= (unsigned char)0x7f;
  output[31] |= (unsigned char)0x40;
```

5. % echo 9d61b19deffd5a60ba844af492ec2cc44449c5697b326919703bac031cae7f60 | ./25519
   `d75a980182b10ab7d54bfed3c964073a0ee172f3daa62325af021a68f707511a` matches results from https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8032#section-7.1

**Everything looks very Kosher using independent sources, and realizing that Monero was designed to utilize Keccak hashing instead of SHA2-256/512 in case SHA2 bugs are discovered that will impact BTC. That is a reason why a RFC 8032 form of ed25519 is not used directly.**