# sc_reduce32 ... is it really supposed to be that complicated?

Tags: monerod, viewkey, privatekey

sc_reduce32 in [crypto-ops.c](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/src/crypto/crypto-ops.c) looks super involved, but according to [MRL-0003.pdf](https://lab.getmonero.org/pubs/MRL-0003.pdf), its just:

> 4.1.11 sc_reduce
>   Takes a 64-byte integer and outputs the lowest 32 bytes modulo the prime q . This is not a CryptoNote-specific function, but comes from the standard ed25519 library.
>   4.1.12 sc_reduce32
>   Takes a 32-byte integer and outputs the integer modulo q. Same code as above, except skipping the 64→32 byte step

Also according to [this question](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2290/why-how-does-monero-generate-public-ed25519-keys-without-using-the-standard-publ)(sorry I don't have enough rep to ask as a comment):

```
import ed25519
import binascii
spendkey_hex = b'77fadbe52830d30438ff68036374c0e3fb755d0d983743bcbfb6a45962f50a09'
sk = binascii.unhexlify(spendkey_hex)

def sc_reduce32(n):
    n = int.from_bytes(n, byteorder='little')
    l = (2**252 + 27742317777372353535851937790883648493)
    reduced = n % l
    newbytes = reduced.to_bytes(32, 'little')
    return newbytes

reduced_sk = sc_reduce32(sk)
```

which in turn doesn't match [MiniNero](https://github.com/monero-project/mininero/blob/master/mininero.py) code:

```
q = 2**255 - 19
l = 2**252 + 27742317777372353535851937790883648493
def sc_reduce_key(a):
   return intToHex(hexToInt(a) % l)
```

I realise MiniNero is hugely outdated and ShenNoether's replacement never materialized. His version/profiles have disappeared from GitHub/Reddit(Noblesir), but I noticed that [Ryan](https://monero.stackexchange.com/users/19/ryan) started [work on replicating sc_reduce32](http://codegists.com/snippet/python/sc_reduce32py_rlittlefield_python) in Python(note he's also the guy who asked Q2290), but it seems incomplete.

I wonder if someone could clarify for me what exactly sc_reduce32 is ***currently*** supposed to be doing, so I can continue/complete replicating it in python(unless someone already has? link please?).

Comment: You should be aware that the Ed25519 implementation uses a highly advanced representation of field points to reduce the amount of computation needed, for example by having bigger than necessary limbs and not modulo reducing after every operation. [You should read section 3 of the Ed25519 paper](https://ed25519.cr.yp.to/ed25519-20110926.pdf).

Comment: @orlp ah, so you're referring to `void sc_reduce32(unsigned char *s)` in crypto-ops.c (wonder if @JollyMort missed my reference?) ... and that all those bit shifts(sorry I'm a noob) are in fact speeding up what `modulo l` does ? I take it that'd be the `Radix-2^51` representation ?

Comment: @kumarz they have to calculate the modulo manually because the number is too large to fit in a "standard" type like an int1_64.

Comment: ah cool, thanks! So if I am doing this in Python, no need to bother with all of that then: Yay :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was almost two questions packed into one here (the title and final paragraph), so I'll answer the other. The function `sc_reduce32` was written to prevent against data leakage via timing analysis. Division ASM instructions and alternate code branches take a variable number of cycles to complete, and the relative timings could leak data to an observer. So the implementation has to perform a modulus operation over an integer value larger than any built-in C integer type without using division, or a single branch (if, while, etc).

Python has built-in support for big-integers; the `%` operator in that mininero sample is deceptive because it is calling a much [larger C function](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/longobject.c#l2539) that is doing similar logic to the `sc_reduce32` function. The python implementation looks different because it handles variable byte length integers, signed integers, and was not written to complete in constant number of CPU cycles.

Answer (score 5):

I experimented with this using javacsript [biginteger library](https://github.com/jtobey/javascript-bignum) and it is what it says - just a `mod l` operation. Endianness and encoding could make some confusion, though.

From your code it looks like the difference is just in the input/output format. One uses a string with base16 encoding, and the other one uses a byte array. They should both represent the same number, though.

Comment: ok many thanks: Yes, I forgot to mention that according to my testing (vs) Luigi's addresscheck the simpler version does actually work.