# Why is sc_reduce32 needed?

Tags: mnemonic-seed, source, algorithm

I recently read a [question about sc_reduce32](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3567/sc-reduce32-is-it-really-supposed-to-be-that-complicated) I stumbled on while investigating on Monero's Mnemonic Seed working. A great tool has been [llcoins](https://xmr.llcoins.net/addresstests.html) which states the following when talking about conversions between the Hexadecimal and Mnemonic seed:

> The "seeds" created by this method will always be valid scalars as they are sent to sc_reduce32 first.

[MRL-0003](https://lab.getmonero.org/pubs/MRL-0003.pdf) defines `sc_reduce32` as:

> **4.1.11 sc_reduce**
>   Takes a 64-byte integer and outputs the lowest 32 bytes modulo the prime q. This is not a CryptoNote-specific function, but comes from the standard ed25519 library.
>
> **4.1.12 sc_reduce32**
>   Takes a 32-byte integer and outputs the integer modulo q. Same code as above, except skipping the 64→32 byte step.

My question can be split in two:

1. Why does the first statement imply that without `sc_reduce32`, the hexadecimal seed would potentially be an invalid scalar?
2. How is `sc_reduce` and `sc_reduce32`'s prime `q` chosen? When looking at [`crypto_ops::generate_keys`](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/src/crypto/crypto.cpp#L111) I have the feeling that it can be a random scalar, not even prime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The paper is incorrect; it's actually mod l, not q. l is the curve order of ed25519. The primary reason AFAIK is that the code doesn't work correctly with scalars above a certain multiple of l. The random_scalar() function outputs an integer

Answer (score 1):

The order for both ed25519 and curve25519 curves can be found from libgcrypt-1.8.5/cipher/ecc-curves.c in hex is **1000000000000000000000000000000014DEF9DEA2F79CD65812631A5CF5D3ED**.

Examine the following that normalizes either an ed25519 or curve25519 private key to their common shared order:

% echo deefd263cbfed62a3711dd133df3ccbd1c4dc4aac21d7405fd667498bf8ebaa1 | sc_reduce32
`9ca838c2c31f1fbad7f030b68a3017ed1b4dc4aac21d7405fd667498bf8eba01`

Contrast the results above to the following 3 command line steps.  Step 1 swaps the endian of the pre-normalized private key. Step 2 normalizes the candidate key to the order of the ed25519 or cv25519 curves using the basic multi-precision calculator (bc) standard to most flavors of UNIX. Step 3 performs an endian swap again.

1% echo DEEFD263CBFED62A3711DD133DF3CCBD1C4DC4AAC21D7405FD667498BF8EBAA1 | rev | dd conv=swab

`A1BA8EBF987466FD05741DC2AAC44D1CBDCCF33D13DD11372AD6FECB63D2EFDE`

2% echo "obase=16; ibase=16; A1BA8EBF987466FD05741DC2AAC44D1CBDCCF33D13DD11372AD6FECB63D2EFDE % 1000000000000000000000000000000014DEF9DEA2F79CD65812631A5CF5D3ED" | bc

`1BA8EBF987466FD05741DC2AAC44D1BED17308AB630F0D7BA1F1FC3C238A89C`

3% echo 1BA8EBF987466FD05741DC2AAC44D1BED17308AB630F0D7BA1F1FC3C238A89C | rev | dd conv=swab

`9CA838C2C31F1FBAD7F030B68A3017ED1B4DC4AAC21D7405FD667498BF8EBA`

Now the real question is what is the purpose of the extra 0x01 tucked on to the end of the results from the sc_reduce32 operation (where 32*8=256) ?  Answer - MUST maintain leading hex zero digits when an endian conversion occurs!

Comment: Interesting question. I verified your calculation, and the 0x01 shouldn't be there.

Comment: Interesting to note that https://xmr.llcoins.net/addresstests.html generates the same 0x01 suffix. Wondering if there are masking bits that will be implicitly applied?

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8032#section-5.1 mentions the encoding for ed25519 is inherently little endian. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7748#section-5 mentions the most significant bit of X25519 MUST be masked.

Comment: Ah it must be related to the range, since the order is 252 bits but sc_reduce is 256 bits

Comment: Also, section 5 is talking about elliptic field elements in the finite field q, while sc_reduce32 is creating elements of the field l with order equal to the curve's order. Also I can't believe this garbage site makes lower case L look like upper case i.

Comment: You may want to make a new question with this content, asking why the last bytes are 0x01.

Comment: The comment with (my bad) to the answer at https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/11944/definitively-answering-a-question-about-sc-reduce32-with-a-simple-to-explain-wor/11946?noredirect=1#comment11075_11946 identifies the answer.  Can't drop leading zeros when performing endian format conversions.