# Definitively answering a question about sc_reduce32 with a simple to explain working example created a related unanswered question

Tags: privatekey

Providing working example for the essence of sc_reduce32 at [Why is sc_reduce32 needed?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6995/why-is-sc-reduce32-needed/11942?noredirect=1#comment11064_11942) created another question.

% echo deefd263cbfed62a3711dd133df3ccbd1c4dc4aac21d7405fd667498bf8ebaa1 | sc_reduce32 `9ca838c2c31f1fbad7f030b68a3017ed1b4dc4aac21d7405fd667498bf8eba01`

The command above is suffixed with the byte 0x01.  Trying to understand what is the purpose of this byte? For the URL above, three major steps was used to compute the normalized private key from the curve order for either ed25519 or cv25519. Another person independently made a similar computation and concluded it was unclear what the traceability for the extra 8 byte.

Answer (score 3):

All sc_reduce32 does is perform `mod l` where `l = 7237005577332262213973186563042994240857116359379907606001950938285454250989`. Byte sequences are little endian.

Your input `deefd263cbfed62a3711dd133df3ccbd1c4dc4aac21d7405fd667498bf8ebaa1` is the number `73151987389341079160941681836269938279688779415452276994447379963081137516510`, and `73151987389341079160941681836269938279688779415452276994447379963081137516510` mod `7237005577332262213973186563042994240857116359379907606001950938285454250989` is `781931616018457021209816205839995871117615821653200934427870580226595006620`, which in little endian bytes is `9ca838c2c31f1fbad7f030b68a3017ed1b4dc4aac21d7405fd667498bf8eba01`.

Your result is therefore correct. There are no 'extra' bytes. The input and output are both 32 byte sequences.

Comment: Question remains unanswered.

Comment: I noticed something. Your output in the previous question `1BA8EBF987466FD05741DC2AAC44D1BED17308AB630F0D7BA1F1FC3C238A89C` starts with `1BA...`, which in little endian would be `...BA01` (since that output is 31.5 bytes, there is a 0x01). I wonder if it's not converting to little endian since the 4 0 bits on the end are missing. Perhaps I made a mistake in my computation, or failed to notice something.

Comment: % echo "obase=16; ibase=10; 781931616018457021209816205839995871117615821653200934427870580226595006620"| bc | rev | dd conv=swab
`9CA838C2C31F1FBAD7F030B68A3017ED1B4DC4AAC21D7405FD667498BF8EBA` != `9CA838C2C31F1FBAD7F030B68A3017ED1B4DC4AAC21D7405FD667498BF8EBA01`

Comment: Try converting `9CA838C2C31F1FBAD7F030B68A3017ED1B4DC4AAC21D7405FD667498BF8EBA` back into the decimal number.

Comment: @skaht You appear to be asking why 0x01 has been "suffixed". Nothing has been suffixed, that's just what the answer mathematically looks like. If you do sc_reduce32 on a different number you may not see 0x01 at the end of the resulting hex string, depending on the number you start with. All 0x01 means is that the result happens to start with 2^248 as the highest bits set. Since scalars can go up to about 2^252, the result string of hex will not always end with 0x01. If this still doesn't answer your question, please be specific about exactly what isn't clear.

Comment: Problem solved.  The issue (my bad) was that that endian conversion is very sensitive to having any leading zero hex digits dropped. This was evident from only % echo "obase=10; ibase=16; 01BA8EBF987466FD05741DC2AAC44D1BED17308AB630F0D7BA1F1FC3C238A89C" | bc
`78193161601845702120981620583999587111761582165320093442787058022659` converted properly to base10 and **1BA8EBF987466FD05741DC2AAC44D1BED17308AB630F0D7BA1F1FC3C238A89C** did not. Thanks for the assistance:-)

Comment: Add an answer to the question, with the content of your last comment skaht.

Comment: koe: "Add an answer to the question, with the content of your last comment skaht." <- That is bad advice. This answer is the detailed and correct answer. The fact  skaht made a mistake in their calculation, the comment thread here on this answer suffices.