# Help compute a public key by hand (in a unix shell)

Tags: viewkey, privatekey, spend-key

I am trying to replicate https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/12288 "by hand" with common unix shell tools only - bc, xxd and openssl.

According to documentation for ED25519, **l** is *2^252 + 27742317777372353535851937790883648493*.

Starting with the same secret key as in the referenced question, I first try to "reduce" the secret with *modulo l*:

```
secret=77FADBE52830D30438FF68036374C0E3FB755D0D983743BCBFB6A45962F50A09
l=1000000000000000000000000000000014DEF9DEA2F79CD65812631A5CF5D3ED
reduced=$(echo "obase=16; $secret % $l" | BC_LINE_LENGTH=0 bc)
# => 1F1D7471A5B82DEC316331C12DC4C9DF59FB1FB44564185281D2C
```

`$reduced` being only 53 characters long, causes an error, because openssl expects 64 chars:

```
# DER (ASN.1) as required by openssl
reduced_with_asn1_prefix="302E020100300506032B657004220420${reduced}"
reduced_in_der_format=$(printf "$reduced_with_asn1_prefix" | xxd -r -ps)
public=$(echo $reduced_in_der_format | openssl pkey -inform der -text)
# => ERROR "Could not read key"
```

I tried to prefix `$reduced` with zeroes, suffix it with zeroes, as well as invert it for reverse endianness before doing so.

The result never matches the expected public key *0f3b913371411b27e646b537e888f685bf929ea7aab93c950ed84433f064480d*.

Am I missing steps or doing them wrong?

---

**EDIT: After adding `ibase=16;` for bc the errors are gone, but the result is still different from the expected `0f3b91..`.**

```
reduced=$(echo "obase=16;ibase=16; $secret % $l" | BC_LINE_LENGTH=0 bc)
```

Comment: Your usage of `bc` is off. You specified an output base of 16 (`obase=16`) but not an *input* base (which defaults to 10). Try setting `ibase=16`.

Comment: This resolved the errors and the length of `$reduced` is now 64, but the resulting public key is still wrong. Maybe some extra step missing?

Comment: Because you can't use openssl alone to get the public key from your private key. See the answers in the post you linked in your question.